# Where to use enumerated types

Tags: java, enums

I have to create my own calendar class (I know one already exists, but we are required to write our own, so I cant use any of the methods from the pre-existing `Calendar` or `GregorianCalendar` classes), and we are required to use enum types. I'm not sure what I would use these for, as I am not too familiar with them.

If it helps, my constructors take a date, month, and year value (e.g. 5, 8, 2011).

Comment: What kind of calendars do you need to support? (Gregorian, Buddhist etc?)

Comment: In that case, days of week and months of year are the obvious candidates.

Answer (score 1):

enums are the weapon of choice when dealing with a finite set of values of the same type. For example:

```
public enum Month {
    JANUARY,
    FEBRUARY,
    MARCH,
    APRIL,
    ... etc
}
```

This makes the use of them *strongly typed*.

You can specify methods to accept enum as parameters, eg:

```
private Month month;
public void setMonth(Month month) {
    this.month = month;
}
```

The alternative is to use String (or int) contants, often called *stringly typed*, but such constants are not typed - methods accepting Strings will accept *any* String - eg "Foo":

```
private String month;
public void setMonth(String month) {
    this.month = month; // Will accept "Foo"
}
```

enum can be used (mostly) like normal classes - you can have constructors (private), fields and methods, like this:

```
public enum Month {
    JANUARY("January",
    FEBRUARY("February",
    ... 
    DECEMBER("December");

    private final name;

    private Month(String name) { // Constructors must be private
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

You can even have setters, because enum are do not have to be immutable (their fields do not have to be final), but it's not advised.

EDITED: More info

enums can not `extends` but they can `implements`, so if you had multiple Month types (for different Calendars) you could do this to keep strong typing. Here's and example of an abstraction of Calendar and Month

```
interface Month {
}

enum GregorianMonth implements Month {
}

enum ChineseMonth implements Month {
}

abstract class Calendar<T extends Enum<T> & Month> { // T must be both an enum and a Month
    T month;

    void setMonth(T month) {
        this.month = month;
    }
}

class GregorianCalendar extends Calendar<GregorianMonth> {

}

class ChineseCalendar extends Calendar<ChineseMonth> {

}
```

Comment: That's great if your calendar class *only* deals with Gregorian calendars. It's not so good if your calendar might need to deal with calendars which don't have "January" etc.

Comment: Do all calendars have the concept of a month?

Comment: @Jon Skeet
I'm only dealing with Gregorian calendars, so this helps. Now, sorry to be so 'nooby' for want of a better word, but I'm still not sure what I could use the enum's in. Some of the methods that I'm providing in the class is: Print calendar for current month, Print current year, Set the current date, Get the current date, Roll calendar date forward or backward by a given number of days/months, and Compare two calendar objects. Could any of these implement the enum type, and if so, how?

Comment: @Bhoemian: Yes, that looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Your first stop should be the [Java enum tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), which I think does a good job of explaining what they are, and when you'd want to use them.

The short answer beyond that is that you'd use them for anything where a value can be one of a certain (finite) number of constants.  I'm sure you can think of at least one calendar-related field which is constrained to a certain range of valid values (and though you're not allowed to use the built-in calendars, take a look at them if you want some hints).